# Get all users from active directory using filter

Tags: powershell, syntax, active-directory, user-management, user-account-control

I'm trying to use below script to get all active users from AD, however, I don't get any results although I know there are data with value 512.

Do you know what I have wrong here?

```
  Get-ADUser -filter {$userAccountControl -eq "512"} -properties Name,userAccountControl -Server myserver.local | Export-CSV "E:\Folder\ADusers.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: whats in $userAccountControl?

Comment: `Get-ADUser -filter {userAccountControl -band [int]512}`

Comment: Caution: `userAccountControl` is a bitmap (i.e., an integer treated as a series of bits, wherein each position represents an on/off state) - see @dev.greg's answer.

Comment: Well, I've tried with -band ... and still got error: Get-ADUser : The term 'Get-ADUser' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a 
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At E:\AD\ad_script_test_2.ps1:1 char:1
+ Get-ADUser -filter {userAccountControl -band [int]512} -properties Na ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-ADUser:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the `$` does not belong. That tells PowerShell that you want to use the value in a variable called `$userAccountControl` and compare that to `512`. Considering that you probably never set a variable called `$userAccountControl`, that means it's comparing nothing to `512` and seeing that it's not true for every account.

Remove the `$` and it will compare the property called `userAccountControl` to `512`.

```
Get-ADUser -filter {userAccountControl -eq "512"} -properties Name,userAccountControl -Server myserver.local | Export-CSV "E:\Folder\ADusers.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: Doesn't work, it seems the syntax is incorrect: "Get-ADUser : The term 'Get-ADUser' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a 
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At E:\AD\ad_script_test_2.ps1:1 char:1
+ Get-ADUser -filter {userAccountControl -eq "512"} -properties Name,us ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-ADUser:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException"

Comment: Sounds like you hadn't loaded the ActiveDirectory module. Do that first: `Import-Module ActiveDirectory`

Comment: If you're still getting the `The term 'Get-ADUser' is not recognized` error, that means PowerShell has no idea what `Get-ADUser` means. Either the ActiveDirectory module is not installed, or not loaded. You need to work that out first.

Comment: You can find instructions for installing here (follow the steps for your version of Windows): https://4sysops.com/wiki/how-to-install-the-powershell-active-directory-module/

Comment: Correct, the module wasn't on test server, when I ran it on prod server, it worked fine. Thanks ;)

Comment: I have one additional issue, now I get the results, which is great, however, I get more than I need. I have specified in -properties that I want to get only Name and userAccountControl. For some reason i'm getting like everything: DistinguishedName Enabled GivenName Name ObjectClass ObjectGUID SamAccountName SID Surname userAccountControl UserPrincipalName; Would you know how can I limit it only to those two?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that with `Get-ADUser`. It always gets the ["default set"](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12037.active-directory-get-aduser-default-and-extended-properties.aspx) of attributes. The `Properties` parameter only lets you ask for more, not less. If you're serious about this, you could try using .NET's `DirectorySearcher` instead. It'll give you more control, but it's a little more complex to work with: https://www.petri.com/discovering-active-directory-searcher-powershell You'll want to set the `PropertiesToLoad` list.

Answer (score 1):

you could try the LDAPfilter syntax

```
Get-ADUser -property userAccountControl -LDAPfilter "(userAccountControl=512)"
```

However, this might not be a good method : userAccountControl is a binary field, each bit representing a binary value (see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/305144/how-to-use-the-useraccountcontrol-flags-to-manipulate-user-account-pro ) 
for example :

512 is "normal account", wich you want

66048 is "normal account" + "password dont expire", which you might also want

514 is "normal account" + "account disabled" , which you might not want

all value would  match

```
-band 512
```

you need to clarify what's an active user.

Comment: yes, I mean 512 status. However, it ain't working. It seems like incorrect syntax.